# Assumption that work done by adiabatic process only depends on initial and final temperature, Rational Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm going through Rational Thermodynamics by C. Truesdell (2nd ed.) and in Appendix 1 (p. 89) he is deriving the constitutive relations between the pressure function $\bar\omega(V,\theta)$, the specific heat at constant volume $K_V(V,\theta)$, and the latent heat at constant volume $\Lambda_V(V,\theta)$. I am doubtful of how he expressed the work done in a Carnot cycle which seems to imply that the work done by 2 adiabatic processes is only a function of the initial and final temperatures and not the volume that they take place at. This implies the constitutive relation that $\bar\omega\frac{K_V}{\Lambda_V}$ does not depend on volume. Before this he only stated 3 axioms which basically defined hotness, defined work done as $L = \int\bar\omega\mathrm dV$, and defined rate of heating as $Q = \Lambda_V\dot V + K_V\dot \theta$, and I don't see how the previously mentioned relationship follows from these.

[image]

He considers the Carnot cycle $\mathscr C$ defined by the 2 temperatures (hotness levels) $\theta^+, \theta^-$ and the 2 adiabats $\phi_1, \phi_2$ and states that the total work done $L(\mathscr C)$ can be written in terms of a function $g_{\phi_1\phi_2}(\theta)$ as
$$L(\mathscr C) = g_{\phi_1\phi_2}(\theta^+) - g_{\phi_1\phi_2}(\theta^-)$$

He goes on to explicitly define $g_{\phi_1\phi_2}$ by its derivative
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}g_{\phi_1\phi_2}(\theta) \equiv \int_{\phi_1(\theta)}^{\phi_2(\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\bar\omega(V,\theta)\mathrm dV$$
and at this point I have doubts. Integrating the above definition gives
$$g_{\phi_1\phi_2}(\theta) = \int_{\phi_1(\theta)}^{\phi_2(\theta)}\bar\omega(V,\theta)\mathrm d V + g_0$$
which means that $g_{\phi_1\phi_2}(\theta)$ is the work done over the isothermal process at $\theta$ between $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, plus some constant of integration $g_0$. So by his earlier expression the total work done by $\mathscr C$ is the sum of the work done by its isothermal processes, and therefore the sum of the work done by the adiabatic processes is $0$:
$$\int_{\theta^-}^{\theta^+}\bar\omega(\phi_1(\theta),\theta)\frac{\mathrm d\phi_1}{\mathrm d\theta}\mathrm d\theta + \int_{\theta^+}^{\theta^-}\bar\omega(\phi_2(\theta),\theta)\frac{\mathrm d\phi_2}{\mathrm d\theta}\mathrm d\theta = 0$$
This means the work done by an adiabatic process only depends on the temperature bounds, and I don't see why this can be assumed to be true. Since this is meant to hold for any temperatures $\theta^+,\theta^-$ it implies
$$\bar\omega(\phi_1(\theta),\theta)\frac{\mathrm d\phi_1}{\mathrm d\theta} = \bar\omega(\phi_2(\theta),\theta)\frac{\mathrm d\phi_2}{\mathrm d\theta}$$
and from his differential equation for adiabats $\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dV} = -\frac{\Lambda_V}{K_V}$, assuming there exists atleast one adiabat crossing through any given $(V,\theta)$ we get that $\bar\omega\frac{K_V}{\Lambda_V}$ is a function of only $\theta$, or equivalently
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial V}\left(\bar\omega\frac{K_V}{\Lambda_V}\right) = 0$$

What am I missing? Can this constitutive relation be derived from the first 3 axioms? Thanks

Comment: see Eq 3 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem, is this what you are asking about?

Comment: @hyportnex Yeah that solves it lol I tried using this before but I was doing the integration in the wrong order so it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I just realized another mistake I made was equating $\int_{\phi_1(\theta)}^{\phi_2(\theta)}\frac{\partial \bar\omega}{\partial\theta}\mathrm dV$ to $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\int_{\phi_1(\theta)}^{\phi_2(\theta)}\bar\omega\mathrm dV$. The bounds are functions of $\theta$ so the partial derivative cant just be taken out and so $g$ is not actually the work done by an isothermal process.

Comment: You've got it! (There is also another "error", $\varpi$ is "\varpi" and not "\bar \omega")

Comment: @hyportnex Ahh I was wondering about that lol. Thanks again

Comment: If you really want to get into the thicket of this subject, I would not recommend it to my enemy, though, then you may wish to read the about the nitty-gritty in Truesdell and Bharatha: The Concepts and Logic of Classical Thermodynamics as a Theory of Heat Engines, Springer Verlag. The Appendix 1 is a shorter version of a few Chapters in the Concept & Logic, but I am warning you, it is not for the faint hearted such as me...

Comment: Interesting.. Ill have to check it out